# jquery animate doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a simple slider with this codes:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="#" id="left-arrow">..</a>
    <a href="#" id="right-arrow">..</a>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        ...
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Styles:

```
#gallery {
    position:relative;
    width:290px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#gallery #container{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:1160px;
}
#right-arrow, #left-arrow{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    z-index:200;
}
#right-arrow{
    right:10px;
}
#left-arrow{
    left:10px;
}
```

JS Codes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
// I must set left position explicitly if not when fetching left position it returns "auto"
// I used position.left property, however. but It doesn't returns left relative 
// to parent insted (I think) relative to document which (I don't know why? It is not 
// according to Jquery documentation which position.left - .offset() is relative to document)
        $('#container').css('left', '0px'); 
        $('#right-arrow').click(function(){
            move('right');
        });
        $('#left-arrow').click(function(){
            move('left');
        })

        move = function (direction){
                .
                . 
                .
            // The problem is here:
                $('#container').animate(left:'+=290');

                // although setting it's css left position doesnt work
                $('#container').css('left', '290px');

                // I return container to use it in console!
                return $(#container');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

I used console to debugging it I found that it properly sets css position to whatever I want but actually it doesn't work
Take a look at:

Console:

```
>>> var x = move()
Object[div#container]

>>> x.css('left', '1000px')
Object[div#container]

>>> x.css('left')
"1000px"
// But It doesn't move in reality
```

I Hate Javascript, Please help me I don't know what is the problem

Comment: _"I Hate Javascript"_ - I chuckled a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my god, I found the problem. the problem was not with my code. There was another element another place with the ID of `'container'` it was in a 3rd party module
sorry guys my fault!! :D

Answer (score 4):

To make `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` css rules to work you need to add `position` css rule to `dom`.

```
div
{
   top:10px;
   left:10px;
}
```

above code will not apply top and left to div but

```
div
{
   top:10px;
   left:10px;
   position : relative;//absolute or fixed or etc
}
```

above code will work.

You have below errors.

**Replace** `return $(#container');` **with** `return $('#container');`

Also **Replace** `.animate(left:'+=290');` **with** `.animate({left:'+=290'});`

Comment: I set top and left explicitly in css rules

Comment: @MustafaShujaie also add `position : relative` and see i am sure that will work.

Comment: @Dispeh see the css #gallery #container